# How can I read a raster in a Geopackage with python?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio, geopackage

I'm having a hard time trying to read (with python) a raster that I've saved in a Geopackage.

I thought there would be a simple like `rasterData = rasterio.open(gpkgPath, layer='DEM')`, but when I run this code, It doesn't show any error, but I can't use `read()` method (to furthermore compute man and min values) for the object, when I do so, it returns a message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "rasterio\_io.pyx", line 240, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.read
ValueError: No indexes to read
```

Another thing I realized is that the other attributes from rasterio DatasetReader object, such `width`, `height` and `bounds` are returning strange values (different from those I see in QGIS).

PS1: There is nothing wrong with the raster (I've already opened it with QGIS software);
PS2: I don't want to use QGIS python packges (I want to use rasterio, gdal, or another package like these).

Comment: You can find GDAL examples from the autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/gpkg.py.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your GPKG contains just a single raster, it's as easy as:

```
with rasterio.open("path/to/input.gpkg") as src:
    print(src.profile)
    data = src.read()
```

If your GPKG contains multiple rasters, you can pass the raster name using the table arg:

```
with rasterio.open("path/to/input.gpkg", table="raster_name") as src:
    print(src.profile)
    data = src.read()
```

Alternatively, they are exposed as subdatasets:

```
with rasterio.open("GPKG:path/to/input.gpkg:raster_name") as src:
    print(src.profile)
    data = src.read()
```

If you want to loop through all rasters in a GPKG:

```
with rasterio.open("path/to/input.gpkg") as gpkg:

    if gpkg.subdatasets:
        for raster in gpkg.subdatasets:
            with rasterio.open(raster) as src:
                print(src.profile)
    else:  # Just one raster
        print(gpkg.profile)
```

Comment: OMG! Where did you find this information? I've searched everywhere and I couldn't find it. Thanks a lot, it worked very well for me. If there is any source you have consulted to write this answer, could you share?

Comment: See also [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/429287/revisions). I pulled this answer together based on the gdal geopackage docs https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html